# How to ask the user for a five-digit input in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

For the program I need to write, I have to make sure that the user gives me a five-digit number which is in the form of a palindrome. The program must check to make sure that the number is a palindrome, and if it is not, that it gives an error.

Does anyone have any idea how to do something like that? I am using Eclipse, if it helps.
Mostly, I just need help making sure that the number given to the program is only five digits, no more and no less.

Comment: Use a `regex` or other method to check if it's a 5-digit number, then use the link above to see if it's a palindrome.

Comment: To be honest, I'm pretty sure that when I check for the palindrome, I can just tell the program it needs to check if digit 1 and digit 5 are the same, and if digit 2 and digit 4 are the same.

Comment: Try reading it in as a string, checking the length of the string, then checking if each character is a digit.  Should be able to follow the link @AntonH posted

Comment: Remember, this is not a place to have people do your homework for you. Show us some code that you have tried, and people here will be more than willing to help you FIX the code you have written or offer suggestions to tweak it.

Comment: Hey this is a pretty valid question...

Answer (score 4):

- Read your data as string
- check if it contains only digits (if you use regex you can also check length like `matches("\\d{5}")`)
- check if it is palindrome by comparing firs character with fifth and second with forth (you can use `charAt(index)`).

Comment: +1 for using a String and not an integer. -1 for not providing details or code snippets (yet). All in all, +0.

Comment: @nrubin29 I suspect that this question is homework so I don't want to give OP full working code. Instead portion of pointers should be enough to solve this problem. Anyway thanks for your opinion.

Comment: @nrubin29 Well he pretty gives the algorithm. The OP can easily write the program for that. +1 for me, there is no need to give all the code.

Comment: @Pshemo Agreed. If OP can't give us any code, why should we.

Comment: @AntonH That's not a healthy mindset to approach SO...

Comment: The perfect way to answer. @nrubin - algorithm and helpful is better than assuming something is homework and nannying. This IS a help facility and in this day and age kudos for bothering to ask for help.

Comment: @AntonH : no one is expecting "we" to do anything. As you see some people can be positive and constructive and guide the beginner. If you can help do. Whining about it isnt helpful, positive or an approach that suggests SO is the place to be.

Comment: @AnubianNoob My comment was a very (too) abrupt way of saying that, if OP seeming hasn't put effort into solving the given problem, nor possibly searching for a solution (the link I gave, right at the outset, is a protected SO article, and is the result of a Google search with 2 words: `java palindrome`), then why should we give a complete code solution. Which is why I agreed with Pshemo's answer, of giving the logic/pseudo-code. But like I said, I was too abrupt.

Comment: We give him an answer because he asked a valid question... That's how SO works...

Comment: To the responses to my comment: I agree with what you are saying. +1.

Answer (score 3):

If you have it as an integer:

```
int n = getUserInput();

// Number is not 5 digits.
if (n/10000>=10 || n/10000<=0)
    throw new Exception();

// First and last digits don't match.
if (n%10 != n/10000)
    throw new Exception();

// Second and fourth digits don't match.
if ((n%100)/10 != (n/1000)%10)
    throw new Exception();
```

If you have it as a String:

```
String s = getUserInput();

// Test that pin is number.
for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
    if (c < '0' || c > '9') // or `if (!Character.isDigit(c))`
        throw new Exception();
}

// String is not 5 characters.
if (s.length() != 5)
    throw new Exception();

// First and last don't match.
if (s.charAt(0) != s.charAt(4))
    throw new Exception();

// Second and fourth don't match
if (s.charAt(1) != s.charAt(3))
    throw new Exception();
```

Comment: Not sure I recommend this.  If the input has to be exactly five digits, is it allowed to begin with a 0 (e.g. 02420)?  That argues for treating the input as a `String` and not as an `int`.

Comment: You probably don't want to throw Exceptions because the OP would handle it then and there with a message. Also, s/he might not know what Exceptions are yet.

Comment: Well obviously you wouldn't throw exceptions like that, but the idea still stands...

Comment: Added code for String.

Comment: You need to check if user passed only digits. Your code based on String will also accept `"abcba"`.

Comment: Fixed String test, working on int test...

Comment: `if (c < '0' || c > '9')` can be replaced with `if (!Character.isDigit(c))`. Also you don't need to check all characters, first 3 will be enough.

Comment: `Character.isDigit()` accepts any unicode digit, which might not be the intended behavior...